# How to Force compiler in autotools with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autotools

I have downloaded some C++ source code project from Internet, which incorporated autotools feature. So, I want to crosscompile it for an arm device of which I have the compiler; however, I don't know how to indicate the arm compiler on autotools parameteres, I have tried to set up on configure option the path to my compiler with CC=pathOfArmCompiler but it doesn't work.

Have you any suggestion of how do it? I was reading of changing the configure.ac archive but I'm not sure if that is the better solution.

Thanks in advance,

Regards

EDITED:

I have tried Jack Kelly advice an using the following configure

```
configure CC=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++  CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32"--host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --with-sysroot=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/
```

I get this errors

```
Command-line environment variables:
     LDFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32" CC="/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++"

sh -c /home/t/ibrdtn/ibrdtn-tools-0.8.0/configure      ++ --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --with-sysroot=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/ 
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: ++
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-strip... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
Invalid configuration `++': machine `++' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub ++ failed
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub ++ failed
checking build system type... 

Configuration failed with error
```

EDIT 2:
The previous errors werer gone after reinstalling eclipse. But now with this configuration

```
./configure --build=i686-linux --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi
--target=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi
CC=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CXX=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++
--with-gnu-ld--with-sysroot=/h/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi
CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32" --prefix=/ibrdtn-svn/dtnCross/
```

Cheking the configure output I got this

```
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-c++... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gpp... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-aCC... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-CC... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-cxx... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-cc++... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-cl.exe... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-FCC... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-KCC... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-RCC... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-xlC_r... no
checking for arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-xlC... no
```

...

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/t/ibrdtn/ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net'
  CXX    tcpclient.lo
  CXX    tcpserver.lo
  CXX    tcpstream.lo
  CXX    udpsocket.lo
  CXX    MulticastSocket.lo
  CXX    UnicastSocket.lo
  CXX    stopandwait.lo
  CXX    vsocket.lo
  CXX    vinterface.lo
  CXX    vaddress.lo
  CXX    LinkManager.lo
In file included from LinkManager.cpp:16:
../../ibrcommon/net/NetLinkManager.h:19:29: error: netlink/netlink.h: No such file or directory
../../ibrcommon/net/NetLinkManager.h:20:26: error: netlink/attr.h: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [LinkManager.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/t/ibrdtn/ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon/net'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/t/ibrdtn/ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/t/ibrdtn/ibrcommon-0.8.0/ibrcommon'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

So I think that the compilers aren't being cought properly, do you know a possible reason?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the path to the arm compiler, and what is the compiler called?

Comment: the path to the arm compiler is something like `code /home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc`  the compiler called by default in autotools is whether gcc or g++, since the macro is `code AC_PROG_CC AC_PROG_CXX `

Answer (score 2):

When cross-compiling an autotooled package, there are three options to `configure` that you want to think about: `--host`, `--build` and `--target`.

- `--host`: what platform will the binaries will run on?
- `--build`: what platform is doing the compiling?
- `--target`: when building a compiler, what platform should it target?

(Yes, this means that it's possible to use a sparc machine to compile a compiler that runs on x86 but targets ARM. That's called a Canadian Cross.)

The argument to these options takes the (general) form of `ARCH-VENDOR-OS-LIBC`, but sometimes one or more parts are omitted. Some examples:

- `i686-pc-linux-gnu`
- `i586-pc-mingw32`
- `arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi`

These are used as a prefix to any *tool* being called (compilers, linkers, `ar`, anything found by `AC_CHECK_TOOL` in a `configure` script).

So the argument to `--host` is `arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi`, but what about `--build`?

Well, `configure` can often guess that (by calling an auxiliary script called `config.guess`), so give the following a try:

```
./configure \
   --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi \
    PATH="/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2pi/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks Jack Kelly, I will try it and post the outcome. But I still have a doubt, with Autotools plugin for Eclipse the line to give configure shouldn't include --host since that parameters is already specified apart in the plugin,should I? So then configure command'd be something like `code ./configure PATH="/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2pi/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: I don't know eclipse, and I don't know eclipse's autotools plugin. What I do know is that if you don't pass `--host` to `./configure`, it won't know that you're cross-compiling. So some of those little tests it runs (by compiling and running small programs) may fail.

Comment: Thanks again, but instead of changing the path, could I set the flag CC to the compiler path like this `codeCC=/home/th/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CC=c99`

Comment: You can try, but why are you setting `CC` to both the path to your compiler and to "c99"? Also you'll still need to set `--host` so it's in cross-compile mode.

Comment: I was making a mistake, I only wanted to use the path to my compiler and not c99, sorry. But now when I do that I get some errors which I have included in the orignal post.

Comment: `sh -c /home/t/ibrdtn/ibrdtn-tools-0.8.0/configure      ++ --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --with-sysroot=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/`. Where did the `++` come from?

Comment: I don't know, I'm going to reinstall eclipse... I have already done, now that error has gone but I still have problems with the main cross-compilation since I was retreived the error in the main post